# Jquery ajax in IE runs code that is not called from anywhere

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, internet-explorer

I met very strange problem in front-end part of web application I am working on.

I have jsp-file and "publish" button (which is link really) in it:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="prePublishCheck();">
                <img src="/documents/private/images/publish.png" alt="Publish"/>
                Publish
            </a>
```

Then function "prePublishCheck()" in the same jsp-file:

```
function prePublishCheck() {
    var url = '/documents/private/checkPublicationAuthForCustomer.html?customerId=${document.customer.id}';

    var messageIfNotAvailable = 'Publication is not available for this customer!';

    var callbackIfAvailable = function () {
        submitAttachmentsIframes();
        confirmPublication(${document.id},
            'Publication',
            'You have to sign the document before publication!',
            PUBLICATION_CONFIRM_MESSAGE);
    };

    checkPublicationAuthForCustomer(url, callbackIfAvailable, messageIfNotAvailable);
}
```

Then function "checkPublicationAuthForCustomer(url, callbackIfAvailable, messageIfNotAvailable)" in separate js-file that is included in the jsp:

```
function checkPublicationAuthForCustomer(url, callbackIfAvailable, messageIfNotAvailable) {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function(msg) {
        if (!msg.Available) {
            customerAlert(messageIfNotAvailable, "Message");
            return false;
        } else {
            callbackIfAvailable();
        }
    }
});
}
```

I debug the front-end code and see that everything works as needed, the ajax respond returns `msg.Available = true` so browser runs code in 'else' branch, I mean it calls 'callbackIfAvailable'. But right after the last function in this callback is complete the page is refreshing and browser shows message that could be shown only by calling `customerAlert(messageIfNotAvailable, "Message");`, but this code could be run only when ajax response returns `msg.Available = false` that is never happening. I mean that IE debugger never goes into that part of code and never calls that 'customerAlert' function.

I don't really know how it is possible at all. Anyone met similar problem? Could you help me please?

P.S. My browser is IE11 that runs in IE9 document mode!

Comment: Are you sure that the msg.Available is being returned as a boolean and not a string?  Because both "true" and "false" are truthy.

Comment: @Taplar, yes I am shure